# Enable ALT+S in Outlook 2010

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

Just setup a new machine with Outlook on it. however, Alt+s does not sends emails anymore. in my previous machine, it used to send emails with simple ALT+S.

any tips around how to enable that ? i found a setting for ctrl+enter but have been used to ALT+S, so would appreciate if somebody can guide how to do it.

Comment: In my - admittedly German - version of Outlook 2010 the S from Send is underlined. It should therefore work. It is also in the official list of Microsoft:  http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/4195/screenshot2020290520122.png (source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-outlook-2010-HP010354403.aspx). Could there be any other software blocking your shortcut?

Comment: its a brand new machine with fresh installation of Outlook, it worked perfect on my old machine. also, Ctrl+enter works fine to send the email, but am so used to Alt+s that its just a bit cumbersome.

Comment: can't find any setting to enable it. Really weird.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and after lots of searching not revealing anything I decided the problem must be local.

In my case it is a third-party app, **Screenshot Capture**, which when running in the system tray hijacks the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> combo (even though it's not defined in Edit → Preferences → HotKeys and Shortcuts).

Closing and restarting the app returned <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> functionality to Outlook 2010.

You may find it's worth checking whether you have this or another application running which could be listening for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut and consuming it.

Comment: @Indrek - thanks for adding the `<kbd>` tags - makes my answer look *much* better. :)

Comment: No problem! If you want to learn more about formatting your posts on SuperUser, see http://superuser.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot enable the hotkey, you can create one with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).
When you press Alt-S, it will fire Ctrl-Enter. This way you won't have to change your behaviour.

The script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32 ; This is the code for the new message window and restricts the command to it

!s::SendInput ^{enter} ; When you press alt-s, send ctrl-enter
```

Install AutoHotkey, save the script as ah ahk-file with Notepad, put the script in the startup folder  and you are good to go.

Comment: This is an amazing tool: it looks like it is the only way to prevent Windows Mail from sending a partially-written email upon inadvertently pressing ALT+S!  Just write !S:: in the script. But I am not able to disable CTRL+ENTER too (in theory +enter::  should do the job).